# Program crash on navigation tool bar click - matplotlib - python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, pyqt4, pyinstaller

I have created a user interface based on the integration of pyqt and matplotlib. I have create a standalone .exe using pyinstaller 2.0 (using the command line in accordance to the program documentation) on my machine (vista 32bit). The .exe runs pretty well in different machines but there is only a problem I couldn't get the answer for on google. I have had navigation tool bars to some of the plots and all buttons work well but one: "Edit curves line and axes parameters" (traditionally the most right one, but don't know if you cannot change its place). When I press this button my program simply closes.

Anybody has faced this problem or has any information on it?

Thank you!

Comment: There are some known issues with the curve edit qt bindings (see github) that have been fixed. The .exe is probably handling the un-handled exceptions badly.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Hoping someone will provide an answer.